# 6v power supply- cut off plug end and use bare wires?

Tags: power-supply

I'm a newbie to electronics and bought an old 1960's wave generator for our kid's science lessons. It requires a 6v power supply and has two posts on the front of it.

Can I just buy a typical wall wart power supply and cut the plug off the end and use the two exposed wires for under the binding posts? I realize I need to be careful with the polarity, but other than that, I was wondering if my main idea is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, assuming: A. it requires 6V DC (it _might_ need AC), and B. your wall wart can supply enough current.

Comment: @uint128_t That's a valid answer, so you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @htownclyde Alrighty, done!

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe*.

First off, your wall-wart needs to supply enough current. If the wave generator doesn't specify supply current anywhere, you'll have to guess. If you post a picture or, better yet, a user guide or somesuch, we might be able to help you ballpark it.

Also, there is a possibility that it requires 6VAC rather than 6VDC. A "wave generator" is a bit ambiguous, but if it's a function generator that outputs a bipolar signal (positive and negative), the possibility of an AC supply goes from slim to likely. Basically, the logic goes as follows: if the device outputs a bipolar signal, it has bipolar power rails, and the easiest way to make bipolar rails is with a center-tapped transformer (or even a simple transformer with two half-wave rectifiers). In either case, an AC power input is required.

If this is indeed the case, you need a 6VAC supply, which will be a bit more difficult to find...

Again, without seeing the wave generator (and perhaps inspecting its insides), it's very difficult to determine whether it wants AC or DC, especially given the vintage.